# How do I check that opened window is closed with javascript?

Tags: javascript

is there any way to detect that which popup window i have opened is closed or not?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// global variable for subwindow reference
var newWindow;
// generate and fill the new window
function makeNewWindow() {
    // make sure it isn't already opened
        newWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com","sub","status,height=200,width=300");

}

function checkWindow() {
    if(newWindow.closed){
        document.write("Window has closed.");
    }
}
</script>
    <form>
<input type="button" value="Create New Window" onclick="makeNewWindow();" />
<script>
    checkWindow();
</script>
</form>
```

I want that when i close the opened window. the function checkWindow() print on screen that "Window has closed." Please suggest me some helping code. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
  var win = window.open('http://www.google.com','google','width=800,height=600,status=0,toolbar=0');   
  var timer = setInterval(function() {   
  if(win.closed) {  
     clearInterval(timer);  
     alert('closed');  
  }  
}, 1000);
```